# Setting automatic backups of MySQL database including table lock etc - MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, backup

We've got a Virtual Server with full ssh and root access running LAMP on Ubuntu Server.

I've got a small computer in the office running ubuntu that isn't being used for anything.
I thought I should use it to make and store (a copy of) our MySQL database backups. However, how do I go about backing up our databases?

MySQL Workbench locks tables to avoid errors, amongst a host of other features, but does not have any planned automatic backup bits planned. [MySQL Dumper](http://www.mysqldumper.net/) doesn't specify that they can keep the database consistent.
[Source for information from this paragraph:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532649/how-to-do-automatic-mysql-db-backup-using-mysql-workbench)

I don't see the point of running a php script on my server and emailing the backups when I have SSH access. Since backups are so important, I figure there must be a standard (or awesome) way of doing it I haven't found yet!

So how do I go about backing up our data? And, preferably, our users, config, etc too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have MySQL installed on the Ubuntu machine, you can do the following:

Suppose IP of Virtual is 10.1.2.30

You can the following on the Ubuntu machine

```
BACKUP_FILE=/root/MySQLData.sql
MYSQL_HOST=10.1.2.30
MYSQL_USER=whateverusername
MYSQL_PASS=whateverpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-h${MYSQL_HOST} -u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} --all-databases > ${BACKUP_FILE}
```

You could crontab this on the Ubuntu machine as well

If you are looking for consistent mysqldumps, you could

- use --single-transaction option if all the data is InnoDB
- if all data is MyISAM, run `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;` on the database
- if data is MyISAM and InnoDB mixed, run `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;` and `--single-transaction` on the database (See my post https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8587/mysql-db-backup-excluding-specific-tables/8613#8613 for some ideas on scripting that)

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I'll give this a shot! Single Transaction option is a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

The script below in a file and make is exe use (chmod u+v file name) then add a crontab entry on the computer @daily file name , and it will dump and keep a weekly backup.

```
 #!/bin/sh
 eightdaysago=$(date --date='7 days ago' +%Y-%m-%d-%A)
 rm -rf /backups/$eightdaysago
 # Backup the mysql Databases
 for database in $(mysql -u b4ckup -pd1psh1t --host server0.expatjob.net -e "show databases" | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v Database| grep -v information_schema | grep -v mysql | grep -v phpmyadmin | grep -v STATS)
 do
    ssh user@ip 'mysqladmin -u (user) -p(password) flush-hosts'
    mysqldump -u (user) -p(password) --lock-tables=false --host ip $database > /backups/`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`-`date +\%A`/$database.sql
done
```